# Blogger: How to disable Lightbox completely?

Tags: html, css, lightbox, blogger

I am using the Blogger SOHO theme for my Blog:
https://www.firozemistry.com

In Settings, if I set the Lightbox option to YES, and a photo is clicked, it opens in the normal full screen overlay - where you click on the "X" to return to the post.

However if I set Lightbox option to NO, the photo opens as a fullscreen image, whereas I would expect the photo not to open at all.

Is there any way to disable opening of fullscreen photos completely? I know I can remove the link to open full size in each photo, but I have over 100 photos on my Blog, and doing that for every photo would be tedious. Is there any way (via HTML or CSS) to prevent all photos from opening fullscreen?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
Firoze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable pointer to links that contain images using CSS `pointer-events` property

```
.post-body a[href$='.jpg'], .post-body a[href$='.png'], .post-body a[href$='.gif'] {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: @ Bassam, Thank you so much! This works perfectly. Best wishes!